Any two points in connected Riemannian manifold can be connected by piecewise differentiable curve with finite length
How can we prove the following statements?

Given a connected Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$, for any two points $p, q \in M$, there exists a piecewise differentiable curve connecting $p$ and $q$.

From the definition of connectedness, we know that there exists a path connecting $p$ and $q$. How can we ensure that this path is piecewise differentiable?

Given a connected Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$, for any two points $p, q \in M$, there exists a piecewise differentiable curve connecting $p$ and $q$ with finite length.

I need these two lemmas to prove that the distance function (defined as the infimum of the lengths of all piecewise differentiable curves between $p$ and $q$) in a connected Riemannian manifold is well-defined. Therefore, I prefer not to use advanced results introduced in later chapters, such as geodesics, to keep the argument self-contained.

Did you mean to say a smooth manifold? Just because a manifold is Riemannian doesn't allow your curves to be smooth. Surely they will be continuous, but smooth? Not so sure about that.

Just do the usual connectedness proof: The set of points that can be joined to $p$ by a piecewise-smooth path is open and closed.

@Snared I think we can assume the Riemannian manifold is smooth, since I'm reading Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry.

@TedShifrin I see. Thank you. Then how can I show its length is finite?

A piecewise-$C^1$ path parametrized by a closed interval has finite length.

@TedShifrin Thanks. I foget the requirement of closed interval when we define path connectness.
